# What is the fastest way to generate a sequence from n to m with large numbers?

Tags: c, arrays, performance, gmp

I'm creating a program where speed counts. I use "default" large numbers (with GMP), so that it is easier to handle for large calculations, when necessary (so I don't have an `int`, `long` or other).

For a feature, I should generate an array containing positive numbers from n to m (e.g. all numbers from 0 to 10). Sometimes I need to generate several million numbers. So I wonder what is the fastest way to fill an array from n to m with GMP numbers (`mpz_t`), knowing that `mpz_array_init` [is obsolete](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Special-Functions.html#Integer-Special-Functions).

At the moment I have this:

```
void generate_seq(mpz_t *res_ptr, const size_t from, const size_t until)
{
    const size_t len = until - from;
    if (res_ptr == NULL)
        res_ptr = malloc(len * sizeof *res_ptr);
    size_t curr = len;
    while (curr-- > from)
        mpz_init_set_ui(res_ptr[curr], curr);
}
```

And I test with this:

```
mpz_t *array = NULL;
generate_seq(array, 0, (size_t)1e8);
```

Is there a faster way? Maybe by using vectorization (I am not familiar with SIMD)?

PS: It's not really a bottleneck, but it's more out of curiosity that I ask this question.

Comment: Does generating even millions of numbers take enough time for you to try and optimize it? There is a saying about "Premature optimization".

Comment: Should `size_t curr = len;` be `size_t curr = until;` ? Something is wrong, if not that excatly.

Comment: If `mpz_init_set_ui` is thread-safe, you can try to do this in parallel. This is probably useful because your `malloc` is big and thus will probably cause a `mmap` and slow page faults after (that could be executed in parallel depending on your OS). You can use OpenMP to do that easily. However, note that if you want to be fast, the best is to keep data in the CPU caches and avoid (large) allocations.